# HTML input form css

Tags: css, forms, input

The problem is with the html input form in which i need the css code for the following attached pic.its a input form and when mouse clicks, the border become blue and have a blur effect...i liked it so much but i don't get the code from anywhere...so please help me...

this following image is sniped from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) in your project and add to your input `class="form-control"`.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes its worked....thnx a lot...and this is the first time im working with bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

It is possible just include one css

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

**HTML**

---

```
<input type="text" class="input-style" placeholder="Text input"></input>
```

**CSS**

---

```
.input-style {
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```css
.input-style {
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" class="input-style" placeholder="Text input"></input>
```